# Android pseudolocalization not working

Tags: android, pseudolocalization

I have added an ar-rXB localization (placed in res/values-ar-rXB/) to help me find unlocalized strings, and replaced each string resource with "木村 政彦" in the Android studio translation editor. Android Studio Preview is showing me the correct strings when I change localization.

I have also placed "pseudoLocalesEnabled true" in the end of app/build.gradle's debug buildType.

When I change my phone's language to arabic and country to XB in MoreLocale 2, all the strings are simply the default value written backwards. Uninstalling the app and reinstalling it with the locale set do not help. I have also tried this with the locale "zz_ZZ"

Is this a problem with MoreLocale 2, my phone or have I missed some part of enabling pseudolocales?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was caused by my misunderstanding of how the en_XA and ar_XB pseudolocalizations work. The compilation process autogenerates strings for the pseudolocales, overwriting my translation.